# Rails cache_counter column doesn't increment on first create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's my code

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actions 
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, counter_cache: true
end
```

Here is my schema:

```
  create_table "actions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "position",        :default => 0
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
  end

  create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          :null => false
    t.integer  "actions_count",    :default => 0
  end
```

My problem is that after the first Action on a project is created project.actions_count is still 0. However, when I create a second Action it increments to 1. What's going on? Why would it just skip the first time?

I have tried multiple methods of creating the Action:

```
action = Action.new(params[:action_event])
action.save

action = Action.create(params[:action_event])

project = Project.find(params[:action_event][:project_id])
action = project.actions.create(params[:action_event])
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here are the lines in the log that are incrementing the actions_count:

First: `SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "projects" SET "actions_count" = COALESCE("actions_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "projects"."id" = 64`

Second: `SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "projects" SET "actions_count" = COALESCE("actions_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "projects"."id" = 64`

Comment: It is probably worth showing what happens in your logs when you perform each of those creation operations. It might also be worth using `save!` and `create!` to ensure than they aren't failing silently.

Comment: Well, I figured out what was going on. I needed to call `project.reload`, then I get the updated count

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, as it happens in the background the count isn't loaded until you explicitly load it. You can answer your own question then :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `project.reload` before checking the value of `actions_count` was all I needed.